# onAuthStateChanged firebase auth creating a user twice React Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

I have an app that I do not need a scenario where there is no user. Once the user lands on the main page a user is created for them anonymously. If they are a user with credentials and they are signed in when they sign out a user `anonymous` should be created again till they sign in again. 
I took a HOC component that was working until I was ready to go into production then I noticed a bug in code where a user is created twice when they land on the index page.

This is my HOC that I wrap my index page and every other page with

```
const AuthHoc = (Component) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

componentDidMount() {

console.log("mounted")   /////this logs twice for some reason I dont know why
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          console.log(user.uid);
        } else {
          console.log("no user");
          var user = auth.currentUser;
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            console.log("there is already a suer")
          } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            auth.signInAnonymously().then(async (cred) => {
              uid=cred.user.uid
              console.log("user created with id", cred.user.uid);
            });
          }
        }
      });

render() {

      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};

export default AuthHoc;
```

and wrapping my index page as

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthHoc(Index));
```

Every log in this code is called twice. The component mounts... **twice** (I don't know why) it finds no user, as it should, creates a user and logs the new user id. The onAuthStateChanged callback fires and logs the uid in the `if user` block of code. Then the problem comes where it reruns the whole process a second time, it creates a user again ignoring the conditionals. 
How best can I improve this code. I need to reuse it across the entire app

Comment: I do not use React.StrictMode in the app.

Comment: In other case AuthHoc must be used for 2 component instances. But please make sure to search for React.StrictMode in your app since create-react-app has enabled it for default